# How to modify a complicated query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this very complicated query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @archivedate date = '5/1/2019'; 

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP((SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(DISTINCT ratechangedate) datecount
                FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive]
                WHERE ArchiveDate = @archivedate
                GROUP BY account
                ORDER BY datecount DESC)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)        
SELECT @cols = (SELECT REPLACE( '
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN ratechangedate END) AS [date <<index_num>>]
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN new_noterate END)   AS [rate <<index_num>>]' , '<<index_num>>', n)
            FROM cteTally
            ORDER BY n
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

set @query = 
N'WITH a AS (
    SELECT a.account,
        dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY ratechangedate) AS index_num,
        ratechangedate,
        new_noterate
    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
    WHERE archivedate = @date
    )
SELECT a.Account' + @cols + N'
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Account;'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@date datetime', @date = @archivedate;
```

I want the same results but without Account being pulled. When I remove the a.Account then I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

My apologies I am very new to SQL so I can understand why this may not be as relevant as it should be.

Comment: There are several spots with a.Account. Which one did you remove?

Comment: That happens because the query ends up as `SELECT ,..`. Arguably the cleanest fix is to put in a `SELECT @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '')` to remove the initial `,`. If `Account` needs to be put back in, just include the comma in the query itself.

Comment: `PRINT @query` or `SELECT @query` are your friend here. Use them to inspect the value of your dynamic SQL, and you'll likely find the reason. Then you can propagate that to the statement that creates the dynamic statement. If you can't find it, include the value of `@query` in your question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Could you provide an answer with the modified code. I tried taking the advice you gave but it gave me a few errors so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: SELECT null [Dont show acoount]' + @cols + N'

Comment: @Serg That worked but then I have a new column of NULLS

Comment: Incidentally, I heartily recommend against `@archivedate date = '5/1/2019'`. Cultivate the habit of using a [language-independent date format](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166771/97345) -- `20190501` would do (or is that `20190105`?). I hope/assume that "in reality" the value is passed as a typed parameter. I'm not posting an answer because I don't think the question or the answer would have much merit -- per Larnu, always `PRINT` the results of a dynamic query and it should probably become obvious what's wrong (and how to fix it).

Comment: Anyone want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to hide the Account from the result set leaving all the rest data the same, change this line

```
SELECT a.Account' + @cols + N'
```

to

```
SELECT ' + STUFF(@cols, 1, <n>, '') + N'
```

as Jeroen Mostert said.

You need to find argument  value that must be the number of first white spaces plus comma in `@cols`. See [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: When I do that I get this: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Print  `@query` and find the proper <n> see updated answer.

Comment: I have this error now:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Finally in should look like `STUFF(@cols, 1, 7, '')` for example. Angle brackets are  denouting a placeholder to be replaced with the real value.

Comment: That runs now but I only get 1 output

Comment: It's hard to say why it is so without sample data to test.

Comment: I can provide sample data but there are many columns and rows. What should I do?

Comment: See this how to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question Sql fiddle would be the best